# ZFCUser and bjyauthorize - How to leave out authorization for landing page

Tags: php, authentication, zend-framework2, zfcuser, bjyauthorize

I'm building a closed website which has a landing page for everyone.

I'm using [`ZfcUser`](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser) and [`BjyAuthorize`](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize/).
Everything works now but I wonder how I can exclude my Application's `Application\Controller\Index::index` action.

In my `module.bjyauthorize.global.php` I told my action to require no authentication:

```php
'BjyAuthorize\Guard\Controller' => array(
    array(
        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
        'action' => 'index',
        'roles' => array()
    ),
    // ...
```

But still I get forwarded to the `ZFCUser` login page.

Any idea what I'm missing?

**Edit:**

I tried it with the `guest` role but no luck so far:

```php
 'default_role'          => 'guest',
 'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\Config' => array(
     'guest' => array(),
     'user'  => array(
         'children' => array(
             'admin' => array(),
         ),
     ),
 ),
```

Comment: Define default role `guest` - make landing page require only `guest`

Comment: i updated my post. I tried it adding `guest` to my role array but i still get forwarded... maybe ZFCUser is interfering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***NOTE***: valid in [BjyAuthorize `1.2.*`](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize/tree/1.2.1)

You have to allow the `guest` user to access the index page:

```php
'BjyAuthorize\Guard\Controller' => array(
    array(
        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
        'action' => 'index',
        'roles' => array('guest', 'user')
    ),
    // ...
```

What you defined in your question is a deny-all instead.

Since BjyAuthorize's controller guard configuration acts as a [whitelist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelist), there is no way to allow access to all roles at once right now.

Comment: I altered my code to your solution but still no luck. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check what your current role is? What's the exception details as displayed by the 403 template?

Comment: oh, maybe a misunderstanding. I get forwarded to the login page, not to the `403`...

Comment: Disable the redirection strategy to debug your problem first.