# Zend Framework 2 - ZFCUser action whitelisting does not work for rerouting

Tags: php, authentication, zend-framework2, zend-route, zfcuser

I'm using [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15897551/1331671) for whitelisting a few actions from the ZFCUser login.

Everything works great unless I redirect to one of these whitelisted pages. For example I have the `myFormAction` which reroutes in case of an invalid form to itself or to a `successAction`.

The problem is now that after clicking the button in any of these cases I end up seeing the ZFCUser login. When I go to one of these pages via URL or link there the first time, it works.

Here is my code for the two cases in `myFormAction`:

*Failure:*

```
return array('myVar' => $myVar);
```

*Success:*

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('myModule', array('action' => 'Success'));
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Is maybe the rerouting not passing the `onBootstrap` function and ZFCUser blocks it somewhere else?

Comment: I'm not sure but it's possible that is coming from that **myFormAction** try with that **myformAction** ?

Comment: no, thats not the problem. I checked it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, that was a stupid one!

There was an error in my link url which wasn't shown because of the `ZFCUser`'s redirecting!

Logging in showed the real path and revealed the error...

Comment: Be sure to flag it as accepted once available. For the statistics ;)